# Are double (or higher order) pointers of different types have any differences?

Tags: c, pointers

AFAIK, the size occupied by *any* type of pointer is the same on a *given* architecture. That is, the only difference between different types of pointers is what will happen when we use an operation such as `ptr++` or `ptr--` on the pointer.

As an example:

`char *cptr;`

`int *iptr;`

occupy the same amount of memory (such as 4 bytes, or 8 bytes or something else). However, the difference is what will happen when we use the increment (or decrement) operator on the pointers. `cptr++` will increment `cptr` by 1, while `iptr++` will increase `iptr` by 4 (depending on the architecture, it can be a different value than 4 as well).

### The Question

My question is, are there any differences between:

`char **cdptr;`

`int **idptr;`

(Assume that for the machine under mention, pointers have a size of 4 bytes)

Since both are pointers, both will occupy the same amount of space: 4 bytes. Also, since both point to something that occupy the same size (again, 4 bytes), operations `char cdptr++` and `int idptr++` will work exactly the same on these two pointers (incrementing them by 4 respectively).

So, do different types of higher order pointers have any differences?

Comment: @nhgrif I don't know what can I do to try this.

Comment: How do you know & understand the first half of this post then?

Comment: @nhgrif I understand all parts of the post. I just don't know what should I check for.

Comment: The memory address (before & after the arithmetic)?  How much space did `++` or `--` move it by for the various types of pointers?  I mean, this truly is basic addition and subtraction.

Comment: > So, do different types of higher order pointers have any differences?
Generally speaking, yes: they are of different type.

Comment: There are no standard requirements about the size of a pointer

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @nhgrif Please don't tell him to try it.  That's like telling someone who's wondering what `i++ + i++` is supposed to do to try it on his compiler and find out.

Comment: I find it to be a good question. Trying on execution will not solve anything. The space moved by `++` for different pointer types might be the same for him, in HIS compiler and HIS machine. It might not be so for me. Or yes, if the standard specifies it that way. But that's what he is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Formally speaking, yes, these pointer types are different.  They have different types, types which are important to the programmer and which the compiler keeps intimate track of.  You can prove they're different by trying to compile

```
char **cdptr;
int **idptr = NULL;

cdptr = idptr;
```

Your compiler will complain.  (gcc says "assignment from incompatible pointer type".)  You can also convince yourself that they're different by noticing what happens when you indirect on them: `cdptr[1][2]` is of course a char, while `idptr[1][2]` is an int.

Now, it's true, since `sizeof(*cdptr)` almost certainly equals `sizeof(*idptr)`, pointer arithmetic like `cdptr++` and `idptr++` will generate the same code.  But this doesn't strike me as a terribly useful fact -- it's about as interesting as observing that if we declare

```
int *iptr;
char **cdptr;
```

we get the same code for `iptr++` and `cdptr++` on a machine where ints and pointers happen to be the same size.  But this doesn't tell us anything we can use while writing C programs.  "Generate the same code when incremented" does not equal "are the same".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in C language, a pointer is more than a memory address. It is a **memory address** AND a **type**.

The type is needed when you use pointer arithmetics. For example: `ptr + 2` means that you shift the current position of the pointer in memory by 2 `sizeof(pointed type by ptr)`.

So, a pointer of pointer differ from a simple pointer by its type... That's all.

Comment: But since pointer arithmetics will work the same for `char **` and `int **`, are they the same?

Comment: I'm not certain that this answer really adds anything that the question itself doesn't cover.  I might be wrong though....